# Accidentally made a 90 GB Partition a Boot Partion

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, grub

Alright, so I had a 90GB partition holding XP, the rest was Ubuntu. I accidentally installed Windows late at night, and forgot it destroys GRUB, so I loaded my Ubuntu 11.04 DVD and used the repair tool. Now when I am on my Ubuntu System I try to use GParted to make that partition to about 500MB, but it doesn't allow me to re-size it. So how do I re-size the partition?

Comment: Is it the 90GB partition you want to resize? What is on it now? Do you need to keep the filesystem on it, or can it be flushed? How does GParted prevent you from resizing it?

Answer (score 3):

Boot your Ubuntu DVD as a live DVD, and run GParted from the live DVD desktop.  Remember to set your BIOS to boot from the optical drive first.

Comment: Also note, lots of modern computers have an option for one time boot selection.

Comment: Alright, so I have done that, now when in GParted I am getting this error: http://i.lulzimg.com/cbe9b34193.png